# ¿Por qué al invertir una cadena los emojis desaparecen?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función en mi librería que invierte cadenas:

```
function reverseText(inputText) {
        x = inputText.length;
        var times = 0;
        var result = "";
        
        while (x >= 0) {
        result = result + inputText.charAt(x);
        x--;
        }
```

Funciona bien con letras normales. El problema viene cuando intento invertir caracteres que se **complementan**, como los emojis; simplemente desaparecen. ¿Hay alguna forma de arreglar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se debe a que JavaScript procesa los datos alfanuméricamente, los emojis tienen una entidad única alfanumérica, la cual es interpretada por el ordenador para convertirlos en emojis, en el proceso de revertir el string, simplemente, se pueden perder los datos porque los emojis NO son alfanuméricos

Podrías usar el [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para separar el string sin uso de [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), una vez lo tengas separado en un array, podrías usar [`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) y después [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
function reverseStr(str) {
  return [...str].reverse().join("");
}

console.log(
  reverseStr(
    "❤ Hola mundo"
  ),
  reverseStr(
    "‍ Hola mundo"
  )
);
```

Ten en cuenta que, el método anterior no funciona para emojis con entidades muy complicadas, también podrías usar una expresión regular para revertir el string

```js
function reverseStr(str) {
  return str.match(/.(\u200d.)*/gu).reverse().join("");
}

console.log(
  reverseStr(
    "‍♂️ Hola mundo"
  ),
  reverseStr(
    "‍ Hola mundo"
  )
);
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! No sabía de la existencia de ese mágico array.prototipe.reverse. Al final funcionó y lo voy a incluir en mi librería. ¡Ten un buen día!

Answer (score 4):

**PROBLEMA**

Esto se debe a la codificación usada por [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) para representar los caracteres.

Javascript utiliza por defecto la codificación [Unicode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) mediante el formato [`utf-8`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), sin embargo los `emojis` pertenecen al estándar Unicode con formato [`utf-16`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), por lo cual para poder representarlos correctamente se necesitan 2 caracteres `utf-8`.

Supongo que ya se intuye que al hacer el reverso de la cadena, estás revirtiendo el orden de los caracteres que conforman el `emoji`, produciéndose lo que se conoce como un [`Mojibake`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Por ejemplo, la siguiente cadena: `"❤"` parece tener 5 caracteres, sin embargo contiene en realidad 9, como se aprecia en el siguiente snippet:

```js
let cadena = "❤";
console.log(cadena);
console.log("Tamaño de la cadena:", cadena.length);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

¿Pero si los `emojis` necesitan 2 caracteres para ser representados, porqué el tamaño de la cadena es 9 y no 10?

Sucede que algunos `emojis` se encuentran dentro del rango de valores Unicode con formato `utf-8`, por lo cual se pueden representar con un sólo carácter:

```js
let cadena = "❤❤❤";
let invertida = cadena.split("").reverse().join("");
console.log(cadena.length);
console.log(invertida);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Así, todos los `emojis`, que necesiten ser representados usando 2 caracteres, se convertirán en `Mojibake` si cambias el orden de los caracteres que lo representan.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución es detectar si el carácter que estamos analizando es un carácter que forma parte de un par que define un emoji o si por el contrario es un caracter sencillo (`utf-8`).

Para ello podemos apoyarnos en el método [`codePointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt), que nos devolverá un valor entero no negativo en el rango Unicode (de 0 a 1114111).

Dado que con `utf-8` el rango de valores es de 0 a 65536, es fácil determinar si un carácter pertenece a una pareja que representa un emoji o si pertenece a un carácter sencillo, evaluando su valor entero.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let cadena = "❤";

function reverseStr(str) {
  if(!str) return str;
  let upperLimit = 65536;
  let arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    if(str.codePointAt(i) > upperLimit) {
      arr.push(str[i] + str[i + 1]);
      i++;
      continue;
    }
    arr.push(str[i]);
  }
  return arr.reverse().join('');
}
let invertido = reverseStr(cadena);

console.log(cadena);
console.log(invertido);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En el código anterior estoy recorriendo la cadena y dependiendo del código de punto (*code point*) del carácter, lo incluyo directamente en el `array` de caracteres o tomo su complemento (`i + 1`) para formar un elemento compuesto de 2 caracteres que conforman el `emoji` y lo añado al `array` de caracteres. Luego, al aplicar el reverso al `array`, no se altera el orden de los caracteres que componen el `emoji`, resultando en un reverso correcto de la cadena.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.