# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los carácteres con tilde de una cadena dentro de un JSON se visualicen correctamente en el navegador con PHP?

Tags: php, json

Tengo este código:

```
<?php
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
   case 'GET':
        if(isset($_GET['text'])){
            $str=$_GET['text'];
            header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
            echo json_encode([
                'original'=>$str,
                'reversed'=>utf8_encode(implode(' ',array_map(fn($w)=>strrev($w),explode(' ',$str))))
            ],JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
break; } ?>
```

Cuando hago una llamada a esa web a través de esta URL: http://localhost/blog/api/invertir.php?text=josé garcía, el resultado impreso en el explorador muestra los carácteres que llevan tilde codificados en vez de mostrarlos bien.

He revisado algunas publicaciones por internet relacionadas con esta conversión de formato y creo que lo estoy haciendo bien, pero en el navegador el resultado no es el que yo esparaba.

Os lo muestro:

{"original":"josé garcía","reversed":"\u00a9\u00c3soj a\u00ad\u00c3crag"}

Lo curioso es que la cadena original aparece bien, pero la invertida no. Sino utilizo la función utf8_encode en la propiedad "reversed" del JSON no obtengo ningún resultado y si consumo esta API desde JavaScript con fetch me devuelve error.

He probado con diferentes combinaciones del segundo argumento de la función json_encode, pero no he conseguido lo que busco.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que ambas cadenas del JSON aparezcan en el formato adecuado y sean perfectamente legibles?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso a `invertir.php`? ¿Puedes mostrar de qué modo estás mandando la respuesta y si has puesto un `header` indicando la codificación?

Comment: En el código que anexé aparece el header. He puesto que sea de tipo text/json y que su charset sea UTF-8.

Comment: No lo había visto. Pero, ¿ese código está en el archivo `invertir.php`? De todos modos, el header correcto para json debe ser: **`header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`**, prueba a ponerlo así, lo demás sobra, no manosees tanto los datos con cosas como: `utf8_encode` o `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Simplemente, pon bien tus `header` y configura de forma global, sea en PHP, sea en el HTML que recibirá la respuesta.

Comment: Tal vez está relacionado con esto: [¿Por qué al invertir una cadena los emojis desaparecen?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477091/por-qu%c3%a9-al-invertir-una-cadena-los-emojis-desaparecen/477107#477107)

Comment: A.Cedano: Correcto, ese código está el archivo invertir.php. Efectivamente no es text/json sino application/json. Fallo mío de transcripción. Lo que me indicas ya lo probé y funciona bien siempre y cuando no incluyas una letra con tilde en la variable que pasas por GET. Si le paso "hola mundo" lo invierte a la perfección y devuelve el JSON correctamente. Si le paso esa misma frase incluyendo la letra "a" con tilde "á", no muestra nada por pantalla. Si hago un fetch con JS devuelve este error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. No sé qué puedo estar haciendo mal 

Comment: php no se ejeuta en el navegador.

Comment: Está claro que hay un problema de codificación y hay dos formas de resolver esto. Una es ir aplicando funciones de codificación sobre los datos sin parar (mala solución) la otra es configurar tus entornos de manera global (HTML, PHP, conexión a la base de datos, base de datos, eventuales archivos) aplicando la codificación que necesitas. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967) he querido abordar este problema ampliamente, precisamente para evitar que escribas código de una forma esclavizante, dependiendo constantemente de funciones como `utf8_encode`-

Comment: Ok, le echaré un vistazo a ese link y probaré opciones. Ya te cuento. Gracias